# Create a grid of user-controls and store them in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, grid

I'm wanting to create a sort of.. pandemic simulation, showing how a virus can affect different countries depending on certain factors such as wealth, population, temperature etc.

I have designed a mock up design of three countries and I would like to put a grid on each of them which I can change colour depending on the status of the grid square (green being non-infected, red being infected and blue being vaccinated) but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

So the question I believe I should be asking is, if I have one user control, how can I duplicate it, change its location and populate an array at run-time? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `Dim newUC as New UserControlName \\ desiredParent.Controls.Add(newUC)`  I dunno where or why an array comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

You can create controls at run-time using the "New" keyword like this:

```
Dim cell As New SomeUserControlNameHere
```

Then you can set some properties on it:

```
cell.X = Y
cell.a = b
```

And then add it to something in the Form:

```
Me.Controls.Add(cell)
```

If you had a Global List, you could add it to that:

```
cells.Add(cell)
```